# Where will Drupal Answers be on November 5th?

Tags: discussion, conferences, sponsorship

Drupal Answers is sponsoring Drupal Camp Indy!

The Indianapolis Drupal Camp will be held at the IUPUI Campus Center November 5th, 2011.  Drupal Answers is sponsoring lunch for the conference, and I'll be there giving out awesome Drupal Answers swag.

The camp is free, but there's a small cost for camp T-shirts.  As a Platinum sponsor, Drupal Answers gets a few camp shirts for free, so I'll give those away to the first few Drupal Answers users to find me on camp day.

I hope to see some of you there!

Comment: This is great, how did you manage to get sponsorship?

Comment: @digital I have to admit that this one was somewhat of an inside job.  I said, "hey work people, I'm speaking at this Drupal Camp about support and community stuff" and they said, "hey, Drupal Answers needs to be there".  However you or any user can say "[hey, we need to promote Drupal Answers at this conference](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/)", and if there's enough community support, and the cost/awesomeness ratio is good, we'll do our best to make it happen!